# Unable to find template: react when using neu create <appname> --template react

Tags: neutralinojs

I've been trying to use Neutralino to build a lightweight desktop app.

Following this article: https://medium.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs-react-starter-template-f504b93a0294

I encountered an error when I tried to use the following code:

```
neu create testName --template react
```

The error says: `Unable to find template: react`

I installed neu-cli using `npm i -g @neutralinojs/neu` with no errors

Comment: Read This [Official Documentation](https://neutralino.js.org/docs/how-to/use-a-frontend-library) For Using Frontend Libraries Which Tells How you can Setup Neutralino With React.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like templates are being removed in favor of a more minimalistic default template. The docs on their page (including the start template) are for version < 2.0.0.

As of version 2.0.0, templates have been removed as a valid CLI command and I've yet to find a good replacement.

For the time being use `neu create *project name*` for the minimal template

Removal of templates source: "we have removed all the templates..."
[See this discussion](https://github.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs/discussions/400)